# import developerprofile to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to import a .devloperprofile to my xcode by following below instructions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/import_signing_assets.html

but I face below error:

[image]

can any one help how to fix this problem?

Comment: You should check what the /Applications/Utilities/Console.app says to have an hint.

Answer (score 0):

In recent xcode version xcode will automatically create developer profile try to implement that check it out